# Compute the exact length of the curve $y = \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)$ from $x=1, x=2$

Tags: calculus, integration

So here is my problem:  $y = \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)$

Taking the derivative:

$$\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2x}$$

And that simplifies further to:

$$\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}=\frac{x^2-1}{2x}$$

Since the formula for the curve is $$\int \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}\right)^2}\textrm{d}x$$
I know I have to square my derivative:

$$1+\left(\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}\right)^2=1+\left(\frac{x^2-1}{2x}\right)^2$$

After expanding and adding $1$, I got the following:

$$\frac{5x^2-2x+1}{4x^2}$$

And I don't know what to do with it from here since the numerator doesn't seem to factor into a perfect square.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You didn't square the numerator correctly.

Comment: @cygorx I don't see where I messed up in squaring the numerator?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy so I can square the numerator and denominator separately since they share common denominator?

Comment: Well, yes.  $(ab)^2 = a^2 b^2$ (until you deal with things like matrices, but in this context $ab=ba$ holds).

Comment: @inquisitor, what? No, squaring a fraction is no more than multiplying it by itself. $\frac a b \frac x y = \frac {ax} {by}$.

Comment: And, actually, I shouldn't have deleted the comment I deleted.  $(x^2-1)^2$ is a degree 4 monic polynomial.  Suddenly confused myself for a second.

Comment: Might I add that this integral works out quite nicely.

Comment: @cygorx I'm sorry, I always get confused because $(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{x}{y})^2$ has to be expanded when they have different denominators.

Comment: @cygorx I got $\frac{1}{2}+ln|2|$

Comment: @inquisitor What was the result of integration?

Comment: @inquisitor Looks like you're off somewhere.  Should be equal to $(3+\ln(4))/4$

Comment: @cygorx I integrated the following: $\int_{1}^{2} \frac{x^2+1}{2x}dx$

Comment: That's correct.  You either got the antiderivative wrong, or plugged in the limits of integration incorrectly.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy thank you and cygorx for your help.  I got the correct answer and verified it on the calculator and wolfram.  $\frac{3+2ln|2|}{4}$

Comment: Note that
$$
\begin{align}
1+\left(\frac{x^2-1}{2x}\right)^2
&=1+\frac{x^4-2x^2+1}{4x^2}\\
&=\frac{x^4+2x^2+1}{4x^2}\\
&=\left(\frac{x^2+1}{2x}\right)^2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}\right)^2}\,{\rm d}x
=
\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{x^{2} - 1}{2x}\right)^2}\,{\rm d}x
=
\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{1 + \frac{x^{4} - 2x^{2} + 1}{4x^{2}}}\,{\rm d}x
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{\frac{x^{4} + 2x^{2} + 1}{4x^{2}}}\,{\rm d}x
=
\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{\left(\frac{x^{2} + 1}{2x}\right)^{2}}\,{\rm d}x
=
\int_{1}^{2}{\frac{x^{2} + 1}{2x}}\,{\rm d}x
=
\int_{1}^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2x}\right)\,{\rm d}x
\\[3mm]&=
\left[\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{2}\right]_{1}^{2}
\end{align}

By applying your limits we get:

$$
l
=
\left[\frac{4}{4}+\frac{\ln\left(2\right)}{2}\right]
-
\left(\frac{1}{4} + 0\right)
=
\frac{3}{4}+\frac{\ln\left(2\right)}{2}
$$

Sorry but it is my first post. took me so much time to learn to use the symbols.

Comment: You'll catch on. Look at how other people format their answers by right clicking on the MathJax and choosing "Show Math As > TeX Commands" (+1)

Comment: Oh thanks. all this time i was using edit..

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis I didn't change anything you wrote. I just add some $\tt LaTeX$. Read the edit and you'll find some advice. Also, you can write your macros as enclosed in $$. That's is very useful. That was a fine answer.